# Where is the link between a Data Source and DataSourceID?

Tags: asp.net

When I attach a Site Map data source type to a site map control, I specify an ID for the data source.
Where in the code (or config files) is that ID associated with the corresponding Web.sitemap file?
Is it that there can be only one site map data source and the ID is actually redundant information?
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataSourceID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.datasourceid.aspx) is used when the source data is provided by another control of type `DataSourceControl` in the page, for instance a [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) control.

[`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) is used to provide the data directly. You should use either, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Look the `DataSource` is a control ,you can find it in the `Data section` of your tool box(ex:sqldatasource,objectdatasource,...etc).

You can set the datasource of your control(gridview for example)through one of two ways:

- The first one is to drag the specific datasource control from the
  toolbox and drop it in your page,then set the `DataSourceID` property
  of your control by the id of the datasource control you has dragged.
- The second one is through the code behind, you can set the
  `DataSource` property of your control then call the `DataBind()`.

---

You can't use both of the two ways at the same time. but you can solve this problem.if you wanna to use the both (each one under specific case or condition)then first you should set the other one by null before you can use the other one.

like this:

```
        gv1.DataSource = null;
        gv1.DataSourceID = ObjectDataSource1.ID;
        gv1.DataBind();
```

and vice versa   .